# chrome://inspect#devices not showing device on network

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug a chromecast application and when I go to chrome://inspect#devices, I don't see anything other than localhost. I've tried adding the IP in manually via the configure button, but I don't get the inspect option.

I'm working in a place with several devices and my coworkers can see all of them. I'm also on the same subnet as the chromecast. Windows 10.

Comment: Further information: Every mac on the network seems to pick everything up. I've looked at one other windows box and it seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is only targeted to debug android apps that contain WebViews.

Very important define in your app´s MainActivity inside `onCreate()` method to enable debugging:

```
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

[image]

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews